# How can delete a field of metadata types in mule once was create?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I need delete a field of a metadata. See the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEHNh.jpg).

I put the field active as string by error and want change to bool.
It's possible?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit this in the configuration XML view?

Comment: i think that the configuration is in this tag <dw:input-payload doc:sample="list_csv.csv"/> ,  and i can`t find the place where do the change.

Answer (score 1):

Not easily, not though the UI anyway. You can regenerate the via 'Set Metadata'

However though the filesystem you can access the metadata file:

`/path to your project/catalog` and then edit the file beginning with the metadata id:

```
<dw:transform-message metadata:id="43f9b9c9-21a0-4b4e-95c0-415ba276d3c5" doc:name="Transform Message">
```

So on the filesystem something like:

```
catalog/43f9b9c9-21a0-4b4e-95c0-415ba276d3c5__md_message_processor__.json
```

Should have content for you mapping like so:

```
{
    "inputMessageMetadata": {
        "messagePayload": {
            "connectorName": "#_custom_mule_metadata_type_#",
            "typeId": "mymap"
        }
    },
    "outputMessageMetadata": {},
    "id": "43f9b9c9-21a0-4b4e-95c0-415ba276d3c5",
    "version": "5.2.0.0"
}
```